# UIWebView stops working after loading an embedded Google Map

Tags: iphone, google-maps, uiwebview

I have an iPhone app that loads a client website into a UIWebView. Navigation between different parts of the website is provided by a UITabBar.

A couple of the client pages have embedded maps or links to map sites (Google Maps and whereis.com.au). When the UIWebView has loaded the embedded map or visited a linked map, it stops working. I get errors such as:

> CALayer bounds contains NaN

and

> CALayer position contains NaN

when trying to switch to another page via the UITabBar.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem when I have a delegate being called for views which are off screen (e.g. changing orientation). I suspect the frame/bounds for an non-visible view are collapsed, to 0,0, causing this problem (divide by zero).

A solution is to set delegate to nil when the view is not visible.